# How can I have Photoshop start and run an action on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, adobe-photoshop, script, photoshop-cs5

I have an action I've created, and it is listed in my action palette:

[image: Picture 2.png]

The action takes the image on the clipboard and saves it to a file.

How can I start Photoshop and run that action from the command line?

Comment: You might be able to create an AppleScript to do this for you, but it will take some tweaking.

Comment: Do you need Photoshop for this? Preview.app does this much more easily.

Comment: @slhck - are you saying I can script preview to take the clipboard and save it to a file?

Comment: Sure, just press `Cmd-N`, it'll create a new document from clipboard, then save it. I'm pretty sure that's easy to script with Automator, possibly the whole thing can be done without Preview.app even.